# Pulling data from OData API

Tags: excel, odata

I am trying to pull large amounts of data from an OData API and preferably, spitting all that data into an excel file. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in general:

First, in Excel, click the **DATA** tab and choose **From other sources**, there should be something called "from OData feed"

Second, if you use Power Query in Excel, click the **POWER QUERY** tab and choose **From other sources**, there also something called "from OData feed".

And also, please pay attention to the version of your OData API, if it's V1-V3, both way should support that. If it's OData V4, as far as I know, currently only PowerQuery supports it.